# Plataforma de destino del proyecto no instalada

Tags: visual-studio, .net

Me acabo de clonar un repositorio de un proyecto en el cual me pidieron participar, pero al intentar abrir el archivo en visual studio 2019 me aparece el error de la imagen, ya he intentado descargar e instalar el Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 desde este enlace https://support.microsoft.com/es-cl/help/4503548/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows, tras reiniciar la pc sigue apareciendo el mismo error, como lo puedo solucionar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al revisar en el panel de control-> programas y caracteristicas me aparece que esta instalado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Problema resuelto: hay que ir al siguiente enlace(https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-developer-pack-offline-installer), descargar e instalar el siguiente archivo "ndp48-devpack-enu", una vez instalado hay que reiniciar el pc y problema deberia de desaparecer